# How can I gather all objects, from all models, within one class based view in django 2.2

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-2.2

A friend of mine is trying to gather all of the data from each of his models within one view, to display on one tamplate, with the 'slug' as the URL.

He currently has a class based view that looks like this:

```
from itertools import chain


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset1 = BooksProduct.objects.all()
    queryset2 = ClothingProduct.objects.all()
    queryset3 = FurnitureProduct.objects.all()
    queryset4 = DecoratingProduct.objects.all()
    queryset = chain(queryset1, queryset2, queryset3, queryset4)
    template_name = 'products/detail.html'
```

The URL looks like this:

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('product-detail/<slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
]
```

The four different models all look very similar to this:

```
class BookProduct(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    stock_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    main_category = models.CharField(choices=PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='FW')
    brand = models.CharField(choices=TOY_BRAND_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='NB')
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:product-detail", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

At the moment, clicking on an individual product to get the product-detail.html view results in this error:

> 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'all'

How is he able to accumulate all of the products from each model into one view?

The DetailView has since been changed to ListView which has made the product details render through to the template, however as soon as you try to refresh the page, or press the back button and re click the product to view the detail page again, it disappears, until he resets the server over again.

The HTML template looks like this:

```
<section id="detail-view">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                {% for product in object_list %}
                <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
                <strong>£{{ product.price }}</strong>
                <hr class="newhr">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-customtwo btn-block">ADD TO BASKET</a>
                <div class="detail-desc-box">
                    <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the view now looks like this:

```
from itertools import chain


class ProductDetailView(ListView):
    queryset1 = BooksProduct.objects.all()
    queryset2 = ClothingProduct.objects.all()
    queryset3 = FurnitureProduct.objects.all()
    queryset4 = DecoratingProduct.objects.all()
    queryset = chain(queryset1, queryset2, queryset3, queryset4)
    template_name = 'products/detail.html'
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use the Generic views out of the box like you're hoping. The reason is because the DetailView is specifically for showing a single model instance. You're attempting to show multiple.

What I'd recommend is to switch this to a `ListView`, supply an additional url keyword argument to the view to specify the slug, then do one of the following:

1. Use [`.union()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union) to make one query to the database and deal with the constraints of that method detailed in the docs.
2. Refactor your [models to use inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) and make the select based on the common model.

Note:
The error you're encountering currently is because you're effectively changing the type of `DetailView.queryset` from `QuerySet` to a generator. The rest of the generic view expects certain members to be present, such as `.all()`.

Comment: So, he changed from DetailView to ListView and immediately it began rendering information within the detail.html page, however if we refreshed the page the information completely disappeared and did not reappear.

Comment: I will attach his HTML document above so make it clear how he is referencing the objects...